# Making samples for HSA branch of GCC compiler

Tags: gcc, openmp, amd-processor

I just recently built and installed the hsa branch of gcc according to the [associated wiki](https://github.com/HSAFoundation/HSA-OpenMP-GCC-AMD/wiki).  Everything went relatively well until I got around to making the samples, vectorCopy and matrixMultiply.  Here is the error output I got for matrixMultiply when running the make command (again, following the recommendations of the wiki):

```
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_region_get_info'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_init'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_signal_create'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_agent_iterate_regions'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_ext_program_create'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_signal_store_relaxed'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_executable_get_symbol'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_ext_program_add_module'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_signal_wait_acquire'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_ext_program_destroy'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_memory_allocate'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_status_string'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_iterate_agents'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_ext_program_finalize'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_executable_create'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_agent_get_info'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_queue_create'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_executable_freeze'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_queue_add_write_index_relaxed'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_executable_symbol_get_info'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_executable_load_code_object'
```

I am using Lubuntu 15.04 with the standard kernel (3.19).  I am using slightly old driver and runtime components that correspond to HSA 1.0 Provisional rather than 1.0 Final, since Okra (which is needed for HSA-OpenMP-GCC) is not yet up-to-date and can not be used with the latest drivers and firmware.  I have "sanity checked" the runtime and Okra, and both tests (vector_copy and Squares, respectively) function properly.  I am also able to use aparapi-lambda successfully with the same setup.

The hardware is an A10-7700k on an Asus A88x-Pro motherboard with 16Gb of RAM.

So, does anyone know why I am getting these errors? I am under the suspicion that the GCC hsa branch has been updated to follow the 1.0 Final specification which is not yet compatible with Okra, which would prevent anyone from actually being able to use the compiler until someone finally updates Okra.  But, I can't be too sure about that.

edit: Here is the new makefile:

```
GCCHSAIL=$(GCC_HSA)/bin/gcc
LDFLAGS=-lhsa-runtime64 -lhsa-runtime-ext64 -lhsakmt -L $(GCC_HSA)/lib64 -L ~/HSA-Runtime-AMD-master/lib -L opt/hsa/lib -L ~/libhsakmt/build/lnx64a -Wl,-rpath,$(GCC_HSA)/lib64  
CFLAGS=-lm -fopenmp -Wall -O3
all : matmul
clean :
    rm -rf *.o matmul test.output
# GCC Specifics
matmul.o :  matmul.c
    $(GCCHSAIL) -c $(CFLAGS) $< 
matmul : matmul.o 
    $(GCCHSAIL) matmul.o $(CFLAGS) -o $@  $(LDFLAGS)
```

The old makefile had no switches making reference to required .so files.  With the new makefile, now I get the following errors:

```
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_ext_program_add_module'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_executable_symbol_get_info'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_executable_load_code_object'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_executable_freeze'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_executable_create'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_executable_get_symbol'
/hsailgcc/lib64/libgomp.so: undefined reference to `hsa_ext_program_finalize'
```

There are fewer errors now, though, for whatever reason, 7 of them persist.

edit edit: Problem solved.  The GCC hsa branch has moved on to support HSA 1.0F and no longer depends on Okra.  That means that the old driver components and old runtime I used to maintain Okra compatibility are incompatible with the present build of GCC hsa.  That should be simple enough to fix.  Thanks for all the help with compiler switches.

Comment: Undefined references are clear sign that one or more libraries are missing during the link stage. A little Internet search shows that library that holds the missing symbols in your case is called `libhsa-runtime64.so`, so you should try compiling your application with `-lhsa-runtime64`, eventually adding the path to the directory containing the library with `-L/path/to/hsaruntime`.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting . . . thanks for the tip! I'll see if I can make good use of your suggestion.

Comment: Okay, see above edit.  Adding various -l and -L switches to the makefile fixed some of the problems, but not all of them.

Comment: Also, I noticed a few header files like hsa.h, hsa_ext_finalize.h, hsa_ext_image.h, and okra.h in /opt/hsa/include .  Could these be missing as well?

Comment: Figured it out; I need new drivers and runtime.